# how to split string ""180101051436_Radmin_VPN_1.0.3448" into exactly two strings in python

Tags: python

how to split "180101051436_Radmin_VPN_1.0.3448" into two strings in python .I want output as "180101051436_" one string and "Radmin_VPN_1.0.3448" second string

Comment: 1. Use regex. 2. If you have a fix number of numbers, use slicing. 3. If you have a variable number of numbers, count them, and slice considering the result.

Comment: `str.split` takes a 2nd argument specifying max number of splits. You can use that. `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])` -- look at python docs for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split after the first underscore:

```
s = "180101051436_Radmin_VPN_1.0.3448"

index = s.find("_") + 1  # get the position just after the first underscore (13)

s1 = s[:index]  # get everything in the string *before* index
s2 = s[index:]  # get everything in the string *after* index
```

Comment: thank you I am able to get the right string.Can you please tell me the logic ,I am not getting. why index is added with +1

Comment: @chetan I added some explanation to the answer

Comment: @chetan `s.find("_")` gets the index of the first underscore. If you split there, then the underscore will be in the second string, but you indicated that you wanted it in the first string, so we add `1` to split just after the underscore. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the optional maxsplit argument to the str.split function.

x.split('_', 1)

Result: ['180101051436', 'Radmin_VPN_1.0.3448']

This does not preserve the underscore that was used to split the string, but it is easy to add that back if you need it.

Documentation reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in case you have to fetch number and rest of the string.

Here is the example:

```
import re

s = '180101051436_Radmin_VPN_1.0.3448'
res = re.search(r'(\d*_)(.*)', s)
print res.groups() # ('180101051436_', 'Radmin_VPN_1.0.3448')
```

Comment: thanks @ikac this way also i am getting the right string